# Adding a color tint to a background-image with CSS

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I'm working on an HTML page. This page allows the user to choose an image that will serve as the "background-image" attribute value for a DIV. The user may also choose a color that will kind of shade the image.

In an attempt to build this, I found this site: http://doodles.tev.net/texture2/. Its doing exactly what I want. However, the code in my app doesn't seem to apply the background-color appropriately. If the background-image value is set, the background-color has no impact. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="height:200px; width:200px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;">&nbsp;</div>

function updateMyDiv() {
  var bg = getBG();
  $("#myDiv").css("background-color", bg);

  var fg = getFG();
  $("#myDiv").css("color", fg);

  var txt = getTxt();
  if ((txt != null) && (txt.path != null) && (txt.path.length > 0)) {
    $("#myDiv").css("background-image", 'url(' + txt.path + ')');
  } else {
    $("#myDiv").css("background-image", '');
  }
}
```

Why does the site that linked to apply a tint to "60 Degree Gray" when I choose a color. However, in my app, a tint never gets applied.

Thank you

Comment: If you need to apply a bg color AND a bg image you may use the shorthand `background` property. However, the bg color always has a lower stack order than the bg image, meaning that the bg image will always be on top. Did you try adding another `div` on top for the tint color?

Comment: Did you notice all the textures on the website are *.png files? I suppose they are semi-transparent images. So you are seeing the background through the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a background image, it will always appear on top of the background color. Background color is usually used as a fallback, in case the background image returns 404, or, the image doesn't cover all of the background.

If you look closer into the site you linked to, you'll see the images are semi-transparent; I think this could be your problem. are your images semi-transparent?